# Parsing HTML using Xpath with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

In .NET there is a lovely library that allows me to easily parse an external html page using xpath queries (HTML Agility Project) - the problem is I have to do that client-side, so only javascript. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You're probably better off just using jQuery's CSS-style syntax.

Comment: Well anyone but IE provides XPath over HTML with the DOM Level 3 XPath API http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/. But within the client "parse an external html page" is restricted by the same origin policy so getting a DOM representation you can apply the `evaluate` method to could be the real problem if the page is not coming from the same origin as the document with the script.

Comment: Well then I assume that what I want to do is not actually possible. Thanks anyway everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery also supports xPath selector as well CSS, you can get more information from the link below.

http://docs.jquery.com/DOM/Traversing/Selectors

Answer (score 1):

You can try it https://github.com/andrejpavlovic/xpathjs

Actually there are a lot of it and there is an window.evaluate method by default.

But the reason why mostly all frameworks using selectors like jQuery/Mootols/Dojo (Sizzle) is that in all modern modern browsers it`s supports almostly native and gets fall back if it doesn't. So in most ways it's faster.