# How to get html code while between two br tags in xpath

Tags: html, xpath, domdocument, php-7.3

I am separating my content for which I am storing in a database table and having it be displayed in TinyMCE (javascript) with HTML5. The content that is in each row, is currently in a descending order, where each date that is being displayed is arranged by oldest to newest. They are each separated by two `<br/>` html tags. And I have decided to use DOMXPath along with DOMDocument for PHP. That way since TinyMCE does not recommend using any root block/tags, and I have chosen this route because I need to have the data arranged backwards from most recent to oldest in order to have it be appended and displayed in TinyMCE. I will be using this code twice, once when I arrange the data backwards in order to view and append new data, and once again when I save the data back to the table row. That way the user does not have to scroll all the way to the bottom of the textarea in order to append new data to the database.

I have already found some code for which the `$xpath->query()` can separate text from each-other. But I also need to see the HTML code that describes and styles each of the text.

I have tried using XML "sections" in order to make it easier for the content, but according to the manual, it is not recommended to use forced_root_block's for TinyMCE, as it could negatively and drastically affect the use of TinyMCE. It would also require the user to have to use Shift+Enter in order to create a new section. Instead by doing so, it will only require the user to remember to place 2 line-breaks each time a new entry is made. I would also like to rely on only using HTML5 code.

```
$sample-data = <<<EOT
09/11/2017
<p><span style="font-color: #FF0000";>Test1</span></p>
<br />
<br />
10/27/2017
<p>Test2</p>
<br /> 
<br />
02/05/2018
Test3
EOT;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($sample-data, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);    

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->query('//br[
   following-sibling::node()[self::*|self::text()[normalize-space()]
   ][1][self::br]
 ]/following-sibling::*/preceding-sibling::text()');

foreach ($obj as $text) {
  //echo $dom->saveXML($text);
  echo $text->textContent . "";
}
```

Unfortunately this code produces twice the amount data, where each sibling seems to create a line-break <"\r\n..."> What I need is this code to produce text, as well as html code that describes and use styles parameter for the data.

I have adopted most of the query from this url [xpath-to-get-data-before-2-br-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36665168/xpath-to-get-data-before-2-br-tags)

But I need to see the HTML code as well. I have chosen to use the following constants. so that my code/ results are not appended with extra html tags.

`$dom->loadHTML($sample-data, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);`

I am also aware that in order to produce any HTML code, that I need to use `$dom->saveXML($text);` I have tried several times trying to place node() and last() in different places, but I could not produce the results that I wanted.

Comment: Too bad none of these spans or divs seem to have a name or id :(  SUGGESTION: if you want to program in Javascript, jQuery might help. For example, [Parsing HTML using Xpath with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580362/).  Otherwise, C#, Java and Python (among others) have many excellent screen scraping libraries, too.

Comment: Q: Why did you remove the "Javascript" tag?  Isn't this fundamentally a programming - a JS programming - question?  Q: What exactly does TinyMCE have to do with this (outside of the fact that you're using TinyMCE as a WYSIWYG HTML editor)?  Q: Apologies - but I really don't understand exactly what you're asking for :(

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help :(  SUGGESTION: Consider updating your post with a) The link to your imgur.com screenshot, b) An example of *EXACTLY* the text PHP receives (I assume that's the highlighted part in your screenshot; I assume it's also the "$sample-data = <<<EOT" section in your initial post), c) Exactly how you'd like PHP to transform that text.

Comment: How about this xpath? `//node()[preceding-sibling::br[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::br]] and following-sibling::br[following-sibling::*[1][self::br]]]`